# bg block colour rollover

Tags: wordpress, hover, rollover, rollovers, rollover-effect

Hi im struggling to insert a rollover background colour behind a a menu on Wordpress. Im trying to achieve something like this yellow band on this site http://alecsoth.com/photography/

this is my css for the menu (at present i can get the grey box and have tried background colour a:hover links but can't seem to get it to work) -

```
/* =Layout
------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#wrapper {
```

width: 80;
 margin: 0 auto;
    }

```
#header {
display: block;
}

#main_nav {
```

width: 10em;
 margin: -2.8em 0 0 0;
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 position: fixed;
        width: 170px;
 height: 100%;
        padding: -18.0em 4.3em 9.1em 5.5em;
 background: #f5f5f5

```
}

#content {
```

width: 80em;
 margin: 1.7em 0 0 0;
 float: right;
 display: inline;
 min-height: 30em;
    }

```
#entry_content {
```

width: 60em;
 margin: 0 2.5em 0 4.5em;
 float: left;
 display: inline;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is use the :hover pseudo-class like so:

```
#main_nav:hover { background: #NEWCOLOR }
```

Just pop this line into your css file and change NEWCOLOR to the color hex of your desire.